# Combining two pictures in Golang

Tags: image, go, glide-golang

I have been working for the past 15hrs trying to combine pitures so that it can have the same aspect like that of nametest

my attempts
In golang , i have succeeded to combine two pictures by creating a bigger pictures and pasting the smaller pictures side by

```
src1, err := imaging.Open("public/images/g8.jpg")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Open failed: %v", err)
}else{


}
src2, err := imaging.Open("public/images/f2.jpg")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Open failed: %v", err)
}else{
dstImage1 := imaging.Resize(src1, 256, 256, imaging.Lanczos)
dstImage2 := imaging.Resize(src2, 256, 256, imaging.Lanczos)


    dst := imaging.New(512, 256, color.NRGBA{0, 0, 0, 0})
    dst = imaging.Paste(dst, dstImage1, image.Pt(0, 0))


    dst = imaging.Paste(dst, dstImage2, image.Pt(256, 0)

err = imaging.Save(dst, "public/images/g8.jpg")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Save failed: %v", err)
}
}
```

With this code, i was able to realise something like this
 http://scholar.myquotes.site/vaumi1.jpg (sorry, i am not yet allowed to post images)
but it is clear that they are two completely different pictures, I want to be able to brush the meeting point of the images in such a way that there is no clear meeting part
. In short i want a result like this one 
http://scholar.myquotes.site/vaumi.jpg
thanks

Answer (score 0):

To put it simply you need to draw one image partly overlapping the other, using a mask with a transparency gradient running from full transparency at the edge of the top image to full opaque at the edge of the bottom image.

You will need to use `image/draw.DrawMask` to do this, and you will probably need to do some experimenting to get the amount of overlap looking right.